# Flash event dispatch question

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, events, dispatcher

I have a question about the event dispatch. I am trying to write the code for youtube player and find the following link..

http://www.codingcolor.com/as3/as3-youtube-chromless-api/

He has many dispatchEvent call similar like this:

```
 dispatchEvent(new YouTubeEvent(YouTubeEvent.ON_IOERROR,event));
```

For my understanding, custom event usually dispatch like below:

```
 dispatchEvent(new Event(YouTubeEvent.ON_IOERROR));
```

I am not sure why he can add `,event` after `On_IOERROR`. I appreciate if anyone would help me about this. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without knowing the API, my guess is that `YouTubeEvent` is intended to be consumed by the API clients, rather than the native flash events (such as `IoErrorEvent`, in this case). So, the code dispatches an instance of YouTubeEvent instead of `IoErrorEvent`. `YouTubeEvent` most likely also gives you access to the original event (through a variable or property) in case you need access to that data.

Regarding your question "I am not sure why he can add ,event after On_IOERROR": `YouTubeEvent` must be a [custom event](http://www.learningactionscript3.com/2007/11/20/dispatching-custom-events/) (a class defined by you or someone else that extends `Event`). So its constructor can take any parameters its author defined.